# Is there a way to drag & drop to copy files between two visual studio instances?

Tags: visual-studio

Is there a way to copy files between two Visual Studio 2008 instances ?  A plugin, setting, or something else ?  Currently, dragging a file from one instances to another does nothing (mouse shows that it's invalid operation).

Right-clicking a file and selecting "Copy" from instance 1, and pasting in instance 2 results in the following error:

> The source files for this operation cannot be found in this solution.

Any ideas or solutions ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Got me the Visual Studio extension [Open In Explorer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tux.OpenInExplorer) that provides a context menu option "copy files". This way you don't have to go over a windows explorer window.

[image: copy files]

Comment: Thanks for sharing !!  I updated this as the new solution due to ease of use, and it solves the issue !

Comment: At first I was reluctant to install additional extensions, but I tried it and fell in love, it's insanely useful! Thanks for sharing this.

Answer (score 18):

About the only way you can do that, is to right-click, Add Existing Item and browse for the file.  Ridiculous, I know, but thats the way it is ;)

Comment: Completely false. The project you're copying from just needs to exist in whatever solution you're copying it to.  If you have two separate solutions open in two separate Visual Studio instances, as long as the project your copying from is present in both solutions, then you can copy from that project in one instance of visual studio into any project in the other solution's instance.  Again, the SOURCE PROJECT from which you're copying files just needs to exist in the TARGET SOLUTION to paste the file into any project in the target solution.

Comment: So the simplest thing to do is add the source project, even temporarily, into the target solution.  In fact, once it's there, you can copy the files right from within the same instance and don't necessarily have to copy from the other instance, but that'll work too.  This is much easier than going into the file system to do it, clicking 'show all files' in visual studio, adding individual files to the project, etc.

Answer (score 12):

Very frustrating, I know.

The thing is that if you copy it directly to the file system, it may not be included in the TSF.
My advice is:

1. Copy, or drag the files from the file system (i.e. Windows Explorer)
2. Paste, or drop them in the Visual Studio Solution Explorer

Worked for me :-)

Answer (score 4):

The simplest built-in way I have found (for VS2019) is:

1. Right click on the source file
2. Select *Copy Full Path*
3. Switch to the destination solution/project
4. Right click on the destination folder
5. Select *Add -> Existing item*
6. Paste
7. Click OK

This will copy the file from source to destination. (Leaving the original alone).

I prefer this as it avoids any tedious browsing through folders.

Answer (score 3):

There's no direct way. One way would be to right click on the folder in the solution explorer, open the folder in explorer, then drag from there into the other instance of Visual Studio.

Comment: At least in VS2012 one can't dragdrop files from Explorer into the Solution explorer of Visual studio. IIRC this was possible earlier.

Comment: Drag and drop into VS only works if you launch the application as Administrator, if I'm not mistaken. (Could also be the other way around)

Comment: This is great when you want copy and paste a folder; works quite easier compared to the Add Existing Item method, in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Just add your source *project* to your target *solution*. That will allow you to copy/paste between the two instances of Visual Studio. This works because Visual Studio's clipboard data for copied files must have a representation that's relative to the project identifier.

Futhermore, once you've added the source project to the target solution, you don't even need to copy between instances, because your source project is in the same solution you're copying to.  You can probably even CTRL+drag files to copy them so you don't lose text in your clipboard.  When you're done, you can remove the project.  This is far simpler than opening multiple explorer windows, copying file, clicking 'show all files' in solution explorer, and manually adding the new files.

When your source project is not in your target solution and you try to copy files between instances, you'll get an error like this.

[image: The source files for this operation cannot be found in this solution.]

This does not occur when your source project (in one instance) is also in your target solution (in another instance) of Visual Studio. Once you understand what's happening, you'll do a face palm, because the error is literally telling you what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Go to file explorer then which files do you want to put in your project, just select them. Now copy those files and paste them on to project. You can also past folders with sub folders and files into project.