# Entity Framework hangs when I try to get values

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, freeze

My program hangs when it gets values using Entity Framework. Here is my simple code:

```
LearningEnglishEntities db2 = new LearningEnglishEntities();
List<tb_Words> searchedItems = db2.tb_Words.ToList(); // it hangs here
```

It's not an async method. There are [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24288898/entity-framework-hangs-when-using-async-calls) about `async` but I didn't find any solution to fix my problem.

It doesn't respond, it's waiting forever. All my code was running until 2 days ago. I didn't type or do anything and this bug happened (short video is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IYec3_DJ1J77tYx998M1mZ4jFnEvhMsx/view?usp=sharing))

I have tried these things so far:

- I removed Entity Framework model from my solution and I added it again
- I created a new program and I used exactly same codes and model (it worked):

  ```
  LearningEnglishEntities1 db = new LearningEnglishEntities1();
  List<tb_Words> sample = db.tb_Words.ToList(); // It worked
  ```
- I [cleaned](https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/visualstudio/ide/building-and-cleaning-projects-and-solutions-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) my solution
- I typed this code:

  ```
  var query = from item in db.tb_Words select item; // It hangs the same way
  ```
- I checked this code is not run by another thread:

  ```
   bool query0 = this.InvokeRequired;
   if (!query0)
   {
       LearningEnglishEntities db2 = new LearningEnglishEntities();
       List<tb_Words> searchedItems = db2.tb_Words.ToList(); // It still hangs
   }
  ```
- I changed my Entity Framework 6.0x version to 5.0x but it didn't
  work.
- I completely [copied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690436/is-there-a-way-to-drag-drop-to-copy-files-between-two-visual-studio-2008-insta) all files and pasted to a new project. It ran but it didn't work
- I restarted Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator Service and checked startup type is Automatically. It didn't work.

Strangely, it works on other projects but it hangs on this project. I haven't found any solution to fix this bug. Do you think what should i do?

Also My Connection String is :

```
<connectionStrings><add name="LearningEnglishEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=DESKTOP-REKGVD4\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=LearningEnglish;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings>
```

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure I have the answer, but it would be helpful if you specified which EF you are using (EF or EF Core) and the version number.

Comment: Is it possible that the table may have too many records, that it takes long time to retrieve data? Try `.Count()` and see what value it returns. Also look at both memory and CPU usage for your client application and the database server. May be the new program that worked was connecting to another database with less records?

Comment: @BryanLewis Thank you for your comment. I've forgetten typing it. I edited my question and I'm using EF 5.0.0. now

Comment: @SherifElmetainy Thank you for your comment. I think it isn't possible because it worked when I tried it by using exactly same database, EF model and codes on other project which I created to test. My Tb_Words table has 14 rows

Comment: Could you show your connection string? Have you defined it in your config file or in db model?

Comment: @MuhammedYusuf Thank you for your comment. I'm typing it right now

Comment: Actually, I couldn't determine the problem but I suggest you to use DBContext. This may fix the problem.

Comment: @MuhammedYusuf Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately it didn't work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all things, I was able to find a solution but I don't know the reason. Using Entity Framework Code First solved my problem. It is not good for my project but i have to use it.